# Typescript Definitions can't be imported Angular2

Tags: angular, hl7-fhir, typescript-definitions

I have been trying to use a typescript definition file from definitely typed and I am having trouble referencing or importing it into the files I want to use it in. The definitions from definitely typed are the fhir definitions. I get errors saying that fhir isn't a namespace or module and I can't reference it in my files. I don't know if I have no idea what I am doing or if it's an angular/typescript problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are definitions available via

```
npm install --save @types/fhir
```

More Infos on [npm @types/fhir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fhir)

Comment: I was able to install it though npm, but I can't get it to work in the actual app. I always try to use the definitions and get this error, [ 5,18): Cannot find namespace 'fhir'.]

Comment: How does your import statement look like?

Comment: Whenever I try to give something a type from fhir like type Address it tries to import it like this. [import Address = fhir.Address;] I have also tried just importing fhir itself and that doesn't work because the error for that is that fhir is not a module. I have also tried using the three /// for reference path and I couldnt get that to work either

Comment: Add the `fhir` tag to your question. Maybe someone already has used the library with angular.